# Are too many if else statements for validation bad?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

From the book Professional Enterprise .Net, which has 5 star rating on amazon, which I am doubting after having a read through. Here is a Borrower class (this isn't copyright infringement, full code is also available from Wrox website):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ProEnt.LoanPrequalification.Model.LoanApplications;

namespace ProEnt.LoanPrequalification.Model.Borrowers
{
    public class Borrower
    {
        private Guid _id;
        private int _age;
        private string _firstName;
        private string _lastName;
        private IAddress _contactAddress;
        private IBankAccount _bankAccount;
        private CreditScore _creditScore;
        private Employer _employer;
        private LoanApplication _loanApplication;

        public Guid Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        public LoanApplication LoanApplication
        {
            get { return _loanApplication; }
            set { _loanApplication = value; }
        }

        public int Age
        {
            get { return _age; }
            set { _age = value; }
        }

        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set { _firstName = value; }
        }

        public string LastName
        {
            get { return _lastName; }
            set { _lastName = value; }
        }

        public IAddress ContactAddress
        {
            get { return _contactAddress; }
            set { _contactAddress = value; }
        }

        public Employer Employer
        {
            get { return _employer; }
            set { _employer = value; }
        }

        public IBankAccount BankAccount
        {
            get { return _bankAccount; }
            set { _bankAccount = value; }
        }

        public CreditScore CreditScore
        {
            get { return _creditScore; }
            set { _creditScore = value; }
        }

        public List<BrokenBusinessRule> GetBrokenRules()
        {
            List<BrokenBusinessRule> brokenRules = new List<BrokenBusinessRule>();

            if (Age < 18)
                brokenRules.Add(new BrokenBusinessRule("Age", "A borrower must be over 18 years of age"));

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
                brokenRules.Add(new BrokenBusinessRule("FirstName", "A borrower must have a first name"));

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
                brokenRules.Add(new BrokenBusinessRule("LastName", "A borrower must have a last name"));

            if (CreditScore == null)
                brokenRules.Add(new BrokenBusinessRule("CreditScore", "A borrower must have a credit score"));
            else if (CreditScore.GetBrokenRules().Count > 0)
            {
                AddToBrokenRulesList(brokenRules, CreditScore.GetBrokenRules());
            }

            if (BankAccount == null)
                brokenRules.Add(new BrokenBusinessRule("BankAccount", "A borrower must have a bank account defined"));
            else if (BankAccount.GetBrokenRules().Count > 0)
            {
                AddToBrokenRulesList(brokenRules, BankAccount.GetBrokenRules());
            }

            if (Employer == null)
                brokenRules.Add(new BrokenBusinessRule("Employer", "A borrower must have an employer"));
            else if (Employer.GetBrokenRules().Count > 0)
            {
                AddToBrokenRulesList(brokenRules, Employer.GetBrokenRules());
            }

            if (ContactAddress == null)
                brokenRules.Add(new BrokenBusinessRule("ContactAddress", "A borrower must have a bank account defined"));
            else if (ContactAddress.GetBrokenRules().Count > 0)
            {
                AddToBrokenRulesList(brokenRules, ContactAddress.GetBrokenRules());
            }

            return brokenRules;
        }

        private void AddToBrokenRulesList(List<BrokenBusinessRule> currentBrokenRules, List<BrokenBusinessRule> brokenRulesToAdd)
        {
            foreach (BrokenBusinessRule brokenRule in brokenRulesToAdd)
            {
                currentBrokenRules.Add(brokenRule);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This class is part of a Mortgage application the authors build.

What is confusing me is that the book is supposed to be about professional enterprise design.

**I am no expert but I don't feel comfortable with**

1- Too many if else statements. (Why not switch?)

2- The class both serves as an entity, AND has validation. Isn't that a smelly design? ( Single Responsibility Principle violation in this kind of book?)

Maybe I am wrong but I don't want to pick up bad practices from a book which is supposed to be teaching an enterprise design. Book is full of similar code snippets and it is really bugging me now. If it IS bad design , how could one get around the too many if else statements?

I do not expect you, obviously, to rewrite the class, just a general idea of how it should be done.

Thank you.

Comment: how about using switch()?

Comment: You would use `switch` is comparing the values of **one** property, not values for many properties.

Comment: it isn't always possible that you can replace if/else with a switch.

Comment: If you don't like its Amazon rating, just write a review about it and give it less stars.

Comment: @DanielDaranas RIGHT after I have sold my read copy on amazon... :D

Comment: As an aside; just because the code is available on the internet, doesn't mean that it is in the public domain and exempt from Copyright protection.

Comment: there is no hard and fast rule as what is the best. if you are not comfortable then whatever the practice it is, it not good for you.

Answer (score 3):

> Too many if else statements

if required then there is nothing wrong with. It is better to check than to catch exception

> The class both serves as an entity, AND has validation

if you are loading something onto entity then validation is required.

i have taken a quick look at the class, and it looks good to me.

Comment: yes validation is required but following the Single Responsibility Principal, there should be a separate object for validation

Comment: @iAteABug_And_iLiked_it Not according to StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2223606/96780.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, nothing wrong with it. While I could see other methods of writing it, the code would not be quite as legible and clear on the first glance.